# Clarification on the validity of separable solutions to PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations

So we know that various famous PDEs have solutions that can be found by assuming the function is a product of functions each in one variable, e.g.

'Let $V(a,b,c)=A(a)B(b)C(c)$' etc.

What I'd like to know is that 1) is this always a valid thing to do (i.e. if it gives you a solution, is it always going to be 'sensible')? And further, 2) if one cannot be found by this method as we usually apply it, does it imply that a solution does not exist? I suspect the answers to these questions are 1) 'yes', and 2) 'yes, it must not exist in the form you have assumed', but I just needed a sanity check :)

To be clear I'll give the example I'm doing, which is fairly simple and so should illustrate it well. I have

$$\frac{d^2\delta\omega}{d\tau^2}=\frac{d^2\delta\omega}{dr^2_*}$$

for some perturbation $\delta\omega$. As a perturbation, I wish it to disappear on the boundaries (here $r=0$ and $r=\infty$.) Would it be true to say that since seeking a separable solution here (say $\delta\omega=R(r)T(\tau)$ gives a product of two waves of the same frequency, if we wish those to vanish at the boundaries the only solution is $\delta\omega\equiv0$?

Comment: Are you really asking about non-linear PDEs or is that a typo?

Comment: Yeah, typo and/or brainfart. Edited, thanks. As I say this might be a really simple question but some assurance would be grand!

Comment: Note I have edited - What I really want to know in 2) is that if a solution can't be found this way does that mean there is no solution in closed form - both in the case of the example, and in the general case?

Comment: Some integral representations of solutions and other forms you might consider to be closed form solutions, without them being sums of separated solutions. However, so far as explicit solutions go, separation of variables is just about the only general technique. And equations may separate in one coordinate system and not another. For the most part you have to find coordinate systems where the mixed derivatives don't show up. That's a limitation. Classical operators such as $\nabla^{2}$ start that way, but it limits the coordinate systems where it separates to a handful of orthogonal ones.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad I could say something useful. :)